# Convert a pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index to an integer

Tags: python, pandas

I used the below code to return the index of a unique ID value

```
n = df.index[df['ID'] == 55555]
```

but n is a value of type `pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index` but I need it as an integer to complete the code below.

```
df.at[n, 'Name'] = 'John'
```

how can i extract the integer value of n ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `[0]`

```
df.at[n[0], 'Name'] = 'John'
```